# How do handle validation error when using create! method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I have a few validations for my votership has_many :through model. However, i'm not quite sure how to handle validation errors since i'm using create! Here's my code:

```
  def cast_vote_up!(user_id, direction)
    voterships.create!(:issue_id => self.id, :user_id   => user_id,
                                             :direction => direction)
  end
```

this is within my Issue model. I have issues and users and users vote on issues via the join model. How do I handle errors in validations since I am just using create! Usually I would do something like

```
if @model.save
   #code
else
   #other code
end
```

but without the .save i'm not sure what to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`create!` will throw an error on failure, but if you use `create` (without the `!`) you can handle the error the same way you do with `save`

```
if voterships.create(....)
   ...if successfully created...
else
   ...if create failed...
end
```

Using the bang (`!`) basically means you're asking your app to cease further execution immediately, if something goes wrong. There are situations where that might be desirable, but when dealing with forms, and user input, you'll need to use the non-bang version because people often make simple typing mistakes that should be caught and dealt with, rather than showing an application error page.